# Javascript to Zoom out on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an app that I am building with JS, PHP and HTML.  The user enters a zip code, there is then an AJAX call to the PHP that queries the database and returns a list of companies within so many miles of that zip code.  The content of the page is then changed to list those companies.

The problem I am running into is that when I click on the input to enter my zip code, the screen zooms in to make the input the width of the screen.  After my AJAX, when the content is repopulated, the screen stays right where it was (at the bottom of the page) and it also stays zoomed in.  I have already programmatically added JS to make the screen go back to the top using the scrollTop function.  Is there a way for me to make the screen zoom back out?

Comment: Maybe http://lab.hakim.se/zoom-js/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `viewport` meta tag in your HTML to disable zooming altogether on mobiles and tablets (as well as most desktops now):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
```

When adding this, the `maximum-scale` and `minimum-scale` values will require your page to always stay at the original size.

Comment: This is a good enough answer for what I needed.  I had seen this in previous posts.  I had just hope that there was a way to keep the zooming effect on the input, but resize after.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @DavidWebb you can always scale the page yourself, which seems like a much more controlled state than relying on the browser.

Comment: Prevent zoom can be BAD for accessibility. If the user is visually impaired and can't zoom into the read text or view an image clearly then they won't be able use your site well.